# Hold back react native UI with async until data from Firebase is fully loaded

Tags: react-native, firebase-realtime-database, async-await

My db is loading fine from Firebase.
How do I write async function correctly to make sure nothing renders until setDATA is set with the data from the db

```
useEffect(() => {
const db = getDatabase();
return onValue(ref(db, "/beaches"), (querySnapShot) => {
  setDATA(querySnapShot.val() || {});
});}, []);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way is going to be to wrap a conditional around the JSX that you don't want to render, and check whether the data exists.

If we say that your data is getting assigned to a variabl called `data`, this would look like

```
return (
    <>
        {!!data && (
            <your jsx here>
        )}
    </>
)
```

Comment: I get your answer and figured out a similar solution. However, being react novice, I am trying to figure out the right way to use promise with getting data from the DB

Comment: This is pretty conventional, actually...assigning network data to some location and not rendering the dependent UI unless that location has data in it